# get URL of dynamic table row

Tags: javascript, css, url, dynamic, html-table

I have a table that is dynamically generated. Each entry is pulled from a database. Each row contains a title, model number, and image - as its own `<td>`.

The titles are all stored like this in the database:

```
<a href="site.com/item_01.php">Item 01</a>
```

so the displayed name can also be a link.

The problem is - only the title is clickable, I can't seem to move the `<a>` tag outside of the relative column. I want the entire row to be clickable now.

**Question:** Is there a way using javascript to get the URL of a `<td>` and apply at to  a `<tr>` that proceeds it? This would have to be all be dynamic, and each row would be different.

(I'm assuming of course to use javascript/jquery to assign the URL to each class.)

Something like this:

```
<tr class="the_url_that_comes later">
    <td class="grab_this_class's_URL">
        <a href="the_url_i need_to_get">Item_01</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Or could I somehow stretch the  across the other columns, maybe with absolute positioning/z-index/display:block??

Thanks for the help, I've never encountered anything like this before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a hack, but should work for this:

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    $('a', $(this)).first().click();
});
```

Translation of code:
For every tr element (every row), make the row clickable, and when it is clicked do this:
Find the first 'a' (link) element inside 'this' (the row that was just clicked), and simulate clicking it.

All that said, ideally, you should store the link as a separate column in your database, and make the title a link in your front end code, instead of storing the link in the title.

Note that this solution requires jQuery.

Comment: Agreed. The URL should DEFINITELY be stored in a separate column if it has to be stored at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it is stored in it's own column.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear, but each name/link column is only `<a href="mysite.com/item_x.php">ItemName</a>`

Comment: If you want to use this method, you should also use CSS to make the tr's cursor into a pointer, so visitors will KNOW they can click on it: tr { cursor: pointer; }

Comment: Right, so what I'm saying is, you should break that into two columns, one for `mysite.com/item_x.php`, and one for `itemName`. Then your front end code can put the URL and the name in the right place.

Comment: It's not a primary key, it's basically just displaying a link with some words. What if you had more than one link to display? Would each link have to have 2 columns?

Comment: Do the two links go to the same URL or two different URLs? You should have one column per URL. Or alternatively use another table with URLs and have a one-to-many relationship, but that may be too advanced for you...

Comment: So you're saying in order to display a link pulled from a database you need to have 2 columns? It's getting rendered as HTML, it works perfectly.

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it's good or the best way to do it. Let's say you want to change the links later, and make them bold or add a CSS class to them... using your current structure, you would have to go into the database and change ALL the titles to accomplish this. However, if the link is in another column, you just need to change the code that constructs the HTML link from the URL and the title in one place.

Comment: Maybe I worded something wrong but I think we're talking about two different things. If I wanted to change the styling I could just do something like `.div td a {css}`. 

What I have in the db is: `<a href="site.com/item_01.php">Item 01</a>`
- That is called as $item_name. There are hundreds of these (item_01.php/item_02.php)
it's displayed with:

`<td>'.$item_name.'</td>`

I don't think I would have to do

`<td><a href="'$link . $item_name.'</a></td>`

Comment: No, we're talking about the same thing. You are doing `<td>'.$item_name_including_link.'</td>` and instead should be doing this: `<td><a href="'.$item_link_only.'">'.$item_name_only.'</td>`.

Comment: You don't HAVE TO do what I'm suggesting, I'm just telling you it's MUCH better to do it that way, and you can see why from re-reading my comments.

Comment: Why split them up? If a change needs to be made I still would have to hardcode it in the table. Is this better for SEO or something? To me it seems better to keep it simple with only one variable...

Comment: Umm... why would you need to hardcode it in the table if you change styles using my method? The table should contain DATA only and not styles or HTML. Your database should not contain any HTML at all.

Comment: To change styles with my version, you change YOUR CODE:
`<td><a class="someclass" href="'.$item_link_only.'">'.$item_name_only.'</td>`

To change it with your solution, you have to change the data... I've explained this a few times already. If you still don't get it, I don't think I can explain it to you.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense if all the links weren't always going be to uniform.

I can't find anywhere on the web that says you shouldn't put HTML inside of a database. What about full-text searches?

Comment: You're not looking hard enough then. Like I said, storing them separately is much more flexible. You can do whatever you like, including ignoring my advice, which others have agreed with.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the url in the table row

```
<tr class="the_url_that_comes later" data-url="the_url_i need_to_get">
  <td class="grab_this_class's_URL">Item_01</td>
</tr>
```

Then

```
$('tr').on('click', function () {
  window.location = $(this).data('url');
});
```